# Eliminar listas vacías de un diccionario en otra lista Python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Tengo dos tipos de datas como las siguientes:

```
data1 ={
     'ArticulosAutores': [], 
     'LibrosAutores': [], 
     'Articulos': [
          {
           'abstract': 'El artículo hace una reseña', 
           'keywords': '', 
           'indice': 'Artículos Publicados de Divulgación Local', 
           'fecha_publicacion': '2005-02-04', 
           'mapeo': [ 
                'Abstract', 
                'Keywords', 
                'Indice', 
                'Fecha Publicacion'
            ]
           }
      ], 
      'Libros': [], 
      'Proyectos': [
           {'fecha_inicio': '2005-02-01', 
           'codigo_proyecto': '', 
           'descripcion': 'Asadsadsadsadsa sadsadsadsa', 
           'mapeo': [
                'Fecha Inicio', 
                'codigo_proyecto', 
                'descripcion',  
            ]
           }
       ]
 }

data2 = [
       'ArticulosAutores', 
       'LibrosAutores', 
       'Articulos', 
       'Libros', 
       'Proyectos',  
       ]
```

Mi pregunta es, como puedo eliminar de `data2` las listas que se encuentran vacías en `data1` por ejemplo `ArticulosAutores LibrosAutores` y `Libros` están vacías en `data1` entonces en base a eso en`data2` obtener un resultado como el siguiente:

```
data2 = ['Articulos', 'Proyectos']
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muuy fácil, solo recorremos el diccionario y escogemos los elementos cuyo valor no este vacío, para eso podemos hacer una compresión de lista o una compresión de diccionario, mostrare ambos ejemplos.

**Compresion de diccionario**

```py
data1 ={...}

#recorremos sus elementos y agregamos solo si es diferente de vacio
data2 = {k:v for k,v in data1.items() if v !=[]}
print(data2)
```

**Resultado**

```
{'Articulos': [{'abstract': 'El artículo hace una reseña',
   'fecha_publicacion': '2005-02-04',
   'indice': 'Artículos Publicados de Divulgación Local',
   'keywords': '',
   'mapeo': ['Abstract', 'Keywords', 'Indice', 'Fecha Publicacion']}],
 'Proyectos': [{'codigo_proyecto': '',
   'descripcion': 'Asadsadsadsadsa sadsadsadsa',
   'fecha_inicio': '2005-02-01',
   'mapeo': ['Fecha Inicio', 'codigo_proyecto', 'descripcion']}]}
```

**Compresion de listas**

```py
data2 = [v[0] for k,v in data1.items() if v !=[]]
print(data2)
```

**Resultado**

```py
[{'abstract': 'El artículo hace una reseña',
  'fecha_publicacion': '2005-02-04',
  'indice': 'Artículos Publicados de Divulgación Local',
  'keywords': '',
  'mapeo': ['Abstract', 'Keywords', 'Indice', 'Fecha Publicacion']},
 {'codigo_proyecto': '',
  'descripcion': 'Asadsadsadsadsa sadsadsadsa',
  'fecha_inicio': '2005-02-01',
  'mapeo': ['Fecha Inicio', 'codigo_proyecto', 'descripcion']}]
```

Como podemos ver regresa un diccionario o lista con todos los valores que no sea listas vacías.